# Is it right? "Have you been struggling with your new year's resolutions like I did?"

Tags: tense-agreement, parallelism

I had been struggling with my new year's resolutions and then I found a solution. The opening question I would like to ask my audience is "Have you been struggling with your new year's resolutions like I had been?". However, the last words "... like I had been" sound a bit awkward.

Can I say "Have you been struggling with your new year's resolutions ***like I did***?" Will it lose the meaning I try to convey?

Answer (score 1):

Using *past perfect* is better since it unambiguously means you are *no longer struggling*

> **Have** you **been** struggling with your new year's resolutions like I **had been**?
>   *I was struggling before, are you still struggling?*

or be more consistent with verb usage

> **Are** you struggling with your new year's resolutions like I **did**?

The first leave the door open that the listener may not be struggling now or possibly struggling on and off, the second means they are still constantly struggling.

Answer (score 0):

A sensible way to deal with this would be to split the sentence.

> Have you been struggling with your new year resolutions? I did until ...

Very often, when something seems awkward, that is your brain's way of telling you that you need to rephrase. Using shorter simpler sentences is often clearer.